# Execute a C# void from javascript function in aspx webform

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a button that executes a delete action to a row in a database. I wrote a javascript function that creates a custom dialog box that allows users to select if they do want to delete the data. However, when I try to execute the private void from code behind inside javascript, it does not run. I have searched through a lot of websites and tried many ways suggested but have not succeed yet. Please help me.

(javascript with asp.net)

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function OnDelete(msg, myYes, myNo) {
            var deleteBox = $("#delete");
            deleteBox.find(".message").text(msg);
            deleteBox.find(".yes, .no").unbind().click(function () {
                deleteBox.hide();
            });
            deleteBox.find(".yes").click(myYes);
            deleteBox.find(".no").click(myNo);
            deleteBox.show();
        }
        function RunDelete() {
            var rvalue = '<%= rvalue.ClientID %>';
            OnDelete("Delete?", function yes() {
                document.getElementById(rvalue).value = "Yes";
            },
                function no() {
                    document.getElementById(rvalue).value = "No";
                });
            document.getElementById('<%=btn_del.ClientID %>').click();
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        #delete {
            display: none;
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            color: #000000;
            border-radius: 12px;
            border: 2px solid #000000;
            position: fixed;
            width: 225px;
            height: 100px;
            left: 45%;
            top: 40%;
            margin-left: -100px;
            padding: 15px 25px 15px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            text-align: center;
        }
 
            #delete button {
                background-color: #FFFFFF;
                display: inline-block;
                border-radius: 12px;
                border: 1px solid #000000;
                padding: 5px;
                text-align: center;
                width: 60px;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
 
            #delete .message {
                text-align: left;
            }
        .auto-style58 {
            width: 65px;
            text-align: right;
        }
        .auto-style59 {
            text-align: right;
        }
        .auto-style60 {
            width: 103px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
    <div id="delete">
        <div class="message"></div>
        <br />
        <button class="yes">Sure</button>
        <button class="no">Not yet</button>
    </div>
```

```
    <asp:Button ID="btn_del" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="DELETE" Width="130px" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="return RunDelete();" OnClick="btn_del_Click" />
```

Code behind (C#)

```
    protected void btn_del_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DeleteData();
        }
```

Comment: Is the javascript being executed? Have you set a breakpoint in your browsers console?

Comment: I answered some of the stuff, but you code is full of errors. Perhaps you have to post one issue at the time. I think this question should be closed because "needs more focus".

Comment: Yes I think I need to look through it again. Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jQuery.ajax()` to call a method in code behind of asp.net webforms.

Step 1: Define `jQuery.ajax()` method then put it in your **Yes** JavaScript function.

```
// HiddenFieldValueID value this is the ID that you want to pass the method
var id = $('#<%=hiddenFieldValueID.ClientID%>').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/WebForm1.aspx/DeleteRowDb",
                data: JSON.stringify({ "RecordID": id }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
```

Step 2: Define your web method in the code behind you need to import `using System.Web.Services` name space and put `[WebMethod]` on the method

```
using System.Web.Services;


    [WebMethod]

    public static string DeleteRowDb(string RecordID)
    {
        //You can do SQL command stuff here 

        return "RecordID: " + RecordID;

    }
```

Completed code

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function OnDelete(msg, myYes, myNo) {
        var deleteBox = $("#delete");
        deleteBox.find(".message").text(msg);
        deleteBox.find(".yes, .no").unbind().click(function () {
            deleteBox.hide();
        });
        deleteBox.find(".yes").click(myYes);
        deleteBox.find(".no").click(myNo);
        deleteBox.show();
    }


    function RunDelete() {
     

        OnDelete("Delete?", function yes()
        {


            var id = $('#<%=hiddenFieldValueID.ClientID%>').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/WebForm1.aspx/DeleteRowDb",
                data: JSON.stringify({ "RecordID": id }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
            


        }, function no() { });


    }
        </script>

        <div id="delete">
            <div class="message"></div>
            <br />
            <button class="yes">Sure</button>
            <button class="no">Not yet</button>
        </div>


        <asp:Button ID="btn_del" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="DELETE" Width="130px" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="return RunDelete();" />


        <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenFieldValueID" runat="server" value="1" />
```

I hope this approach helps you.

Comment: By the way, do you know any idea how to skip the return "RecordID: " + RecordID;? It shows the dialog box every time I execute, which I do not want at all.

Comment: You can remove this part from ajax
 `, success: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);  }`

Comment: Thank you so much. My bad that I did not notice the response function.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of different errors in this code.

Modal dialog code does not look to me like it's doing anything useful. Perhaps your `deleteBox.find(".yes").click(myYes);` is supposed to be `deleteBox.find(".yes").addEventListener('click', myYes);`. Here is MDN documentation for [click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) and for [click event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event).

But even if you make your dialog works, it seems that in your current code you have circular calls. `btn_del` client-side click calls `RunDelete()`, which in turn clicks `btn_del` again, which in turn calls `RunDelete()` again.

Instead of clicking the button again within the click handler, you have to execute postback, adding button ID as a parameter, so that ASP.NET WebForms code on the server knows which element executed postback:

```js
__doPostBack('<%=btn_del.ClientID %>','');
```

So, full `RunDelete()` function should look like this:

```js
function RunDelete() {
  // Correct modal dialog code here...

  __doPostBack('<%=btn_del.ClientID %>','');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why using asp elements if you use asp elements then directly call from there javascript function. You are calling a javascript function inside cs file. It does not allow you invoke.
Try this one

```
<button ID="btn_del" Font-Bold="True" Text="DELETE" Width="130px" UseSubmitBehavior="false"  OnClick="DeleteData()" />
```

Try this one it will work.

Comment: Thank you Luqman but it seems like the button tag it says "this name contains uppercase characters, which is not allowed.